# How useful is a master's degree if you're working in IT-consulting?

Tags: university, academic-life, work-life-balance

I'm currently working as a Software Developer (Azure, .NET, Scrum) for clients. I currently have an applied bachelor's degree in IT. I'm considering to do a parttime master but I'm wondering what the added value is. I mostly study for my IT-certifications. If I obtain a master degree in business and IT, what value does it really have?

Comment: I think you'll get better answers from people in IT consulting rather than a bunch of professors.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, some of us also do consulting of various kinds. Consulting to multinationals can keep you abreast of what trends are like in the real world. Especially in computing, perhaps.

Comment: "_If I obtain a master degree in business and IT, what value does it really have?_" You'll have a master's degree.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that a masters can help your career. For one, the credential might bring you a few more clients and will probably increase their early faith in your skills.

But, if you choose the right program you might get some additional skills (mad skilz) that actually make you more effective in consulting.

As a bonus, it might also get you thinking more about your career choices and options. Who knows. You might even meet some interesting people.